# Как преобразовать int в bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, микроконтроллеры, esp8266, micropython

Работаю с контроллером `ESP8266` на прошивке `MicroPython`, получаю данные по шине `I2C`; для конфигурирования контроллера мне требуется посылать одиночные байты для записи в регистры.

Ввиду того что функции работы с `I2С` принимают на ввод/вывод только объекты типа `bytes` необходимо данные для конфигурации хранить именно в этим виде, что крайне неудобно.

Выглядит так:

```
__scales = {
    "0.88":[b'\x00', 0.73],
    "1.3": [b'\x20', 0.92],
    "1.9": [b'\x40', 1.22],
    "2.5": [b'\x60', 1.52],
    "4.0": [b'\x80', 2.27],
    "4.7": [b'\xA0', 2.56],
    "5.6": [b'\xC0', 3.03],
    "8.1": [b'\xE0', 4.35]}
```

Врианты решения:

1. Составить таблицу конфигурационных байтов табличным способом, записать в файл и забыть.

Минусы данного решения: бешенный объём таблицы; крайне слабая пригодность для внесения модификаций.

2. Работать с данными в числовом виде. Составлять конфигурационные параметры посредством наложения масок.

Например:

```
>>> d = 0b00000000
>>> c = 0b10000001
>>> bin (c | (1 << 4))
'0b10010001'
```

Тут-то и возникает проблема: мне не известно как преобразоавть полученный объект типа `int` в объект типа `bytes`.

Как это сделать ресурсами самого языка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Py3 есть специальный метод как раз для такого случая [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).

```
a = 123
a.to_bytes(8, byteorder='big', signed=true)
>>> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{'
```

Первый аргумент - собственно, количество байтов. Если 8 много, используйте столько, сколько необходимо.

Минус - недоступно на второй версии.

Есть другой выход, который подходит для всех версий: модуль [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack), который сериализует простые типы. Для этого используется специальная [таблица форматов](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), в которой также можно указывать размер и порядок следования байтов (endiannes). Например, `I` - это беззнаковое целое в 4 байта, а `>` - порядок BigEndian. Для 8 байтов со знаком подойдет `q`:

```
import struct

a = 123

print(struct.pack(">q", a))

>>> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{'
```

Опять-таки, если 8 - много, то есть `C`, то есть `char` - 1 байт.

Comment: Разве не *B* для *байта*?