# Pyserial, некорректный аутпут

Tags: python, serial, rs232

Отправляю значение 51, считывая один байт получаю число 5, хотя числа до 255 записываются одним байтом в чем может быть ошибка?

```
import serial
i = 0
serialport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1)

while True:
    i += 1
    serialport.write(b'51')
    rcv = serialport.read(1)
    print(rcv)
    if i == 1:
        break
    serialport.close()
    print('Port is close')
```

Comment: Числа да, но там ведь два байта: `print([c for c in b'51'])  # [53, 49]`

Comment: Хорошо, как можно было бы написать число 51 в одном байте?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654794/201445